# Store in a PHP session variable the width of an image as it is displayed on the screen

Tags: php, image, variables, session, width

I have the following html code that resizes an image:

```
<img  id="my_image" src= "path_to/my_image.png" 
      style="max-width:50%;
             max-height:50%;
             width: auto;
             height: auto;"    />
```

In the same file, I would like to store in a PHP Session variable the width of the image as it is displayed on the screen (i.e., not the width of the original image my_image.png). Do you know how to do it? Thanks a lot.

---

In the same file, I can write a Javascript:

```
<?php  
session_start();
$_SESSION['currentWidth'] = "<script>
                             var img = document.getElementById('my_image'); 
                             document.write(img.clientWidth)
                             </script> 
                            "; 
echo $_SESSION['currentWidth'];
?>
```

And it works well. But as soon as I load another PHP page, `$_SESSION['currentWidth']` is then empty.

Comment: PHP is executed BEFORE the page is sent to the browser. JavaScript is executed AFTER the page is loaded into the browser. Do you see the problem? The only way that you can store the information is via AJAX.

Comment: Hi Jeff. Thank you for your answer. I knew that the problem with my code came from JavaScript being executed after PHP. This sample code was meant to illustrate what I would like to do. I have never used AJAX; I will have a look. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>
    const image = new Image();
    image.onload = function() {
        document.cookie = 'imgWidth=' + this.width;
        document.cookie = 'imgHeight=' + this.height;
    }
    image.src = 'http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif';
</script>
<?php
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($_COOKIE);
    echo '</pre>';
    exit;
?>
```

Comment: Hi Rapheal. Thank you for your suggestion. What if this is an image that  is displayed on the same page as where I run the script?  I will update my post to be clearer about that

Answer (score 0):

Via AJAX:

```
<script>
$( document ).ready( function() {
     $( "#my_image" ).on( "unload").on( "load", function() {
       var width =  document.getElementById("my_image").width ;
       var height =  document.getElementById("my_image").height;       
       $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "updateSessionSize.php",
          data:  { "widthAjax": width, "heightAjax":height },
          success: function(status){

          }
       });
   return false;
        } ).each(function() {
              if (this.complete) $(this).trigger('load');
        });
} );
</script>
```

with updateSessionSize.php:

```
<?php
   session_start();
   $_SESSION["sizeX"] = $_POST["widthAjax"];
   $_SESSION["sizeY"] = $_POST["heightAjax"];
?>
```

Thank you for the tips.